# Symbolic link between two symbolic links

Tags: linux, symlink

It is possible to make a symbolic link between two symbolic link ?
like this:

```
root # ls -al /usr/sbin/ash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Mar 23 20:59 /usr/sbin/ash -> /usr/sbin/busybox

root # ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 23 21:00 /bin/sh -> /usr/sbin/ash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can create them like that:

```
ln -s /usr/sbin/busybox /usr/sbin/ash
ln -s /usr/sbin/ash /bin/sh
```